# C++ Homework: I keep getting an error

Tags: c++

The question is:

> Write a program that reads an integer and displays, using asterisks, a filled and hollow square, placed next to each other.

This is the modified source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
void printTop (int a);
int main() {
int num = 1;
cout << "Please, Enter a Number: " ;
cin >> num;
while (num >= 1) {
    printTop (num);
    for (int w = 0; w < num-2; w++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << " *";
        for (int i = 0; i < num-2; i++) {
            cout << "*\n";
        }
        printTop (num);
        cin >> num;
    }
    return 0;
 }
   void printTop (int a) ;
 {

    for (int i = 0; i < a*2; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
        if (i == a-1) {
            cout << " " ; 
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" ;
}
```

Comment: The error is "printTop was not declared"

Comment: Because you didnt declare printTop....... It litterarly says it in the error

Answer (score 2):

You must declare printTop() above the main method. C++ compilers expect methods to be forward declared (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java and some other languages, C++ does not allow methods to be invoked before they were declared.

You can put the following **declaration** before your `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` method:

```
void PrintTop(int a);
```

However, you don't need to put the function's **definition** before `main`. The declaration is suffice.

Some other problems from your code: `for (int w = 0; w < num-2; i++)` should be replaced by `for (int w = 0; w < num-2; w++)`.

Comment: Okay, that fixed that problem. It now says that int i was not declared. but i declared it in the while loop

Comment: @lampig This line for (int w = 0; w < num-2; i++) has some problems. It will stuck in the loop if you define i blindly. You need to replace i++ by w++.

Comment: It is now saying for a is not declared. But i declared it here void printTop (int a)

Comment: @Iampig On which line does the compiler give you the warning?

Comment: i mean 24 actually

Comment: @Iampig Did you replace `i = a - 1` by `i == a-1` as suggested by songyuanyao?

Comment: yes. this is what it says  'a' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Iampig Can you provide the modified source code again?

Comment: @Iampig The semicolon in the second occurrence of `void printTop (int a); ` need to be removed.

Comment: @Iampig Remove the `;` after `void printTop (int a)`.

Comment: No languages allow invoking methods before they **were** declared. There Compilers can wait until the end of declarations but its not what you said and has nothing to with C - Java differences.

Comment: @bedbad Thanks. I have fixed it.

Comment: makes no sense but now it says this: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Comment: I think it might be my compiler. I am using an online one because code blocks wouldnt load

Comment: @Iampig Your compiler has no problems. The closing curly bracket for `main` does not exist. Put a `}` before `void printTop (int a)`.

Comment: @Iampig The curly brackets do not match. You need a `}` before `void printTop (int a){ ... }` so that the `main` function can be closed properly.